# Python: Have a function call another function with the argument already input

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a function that calls another function with the argument already input? I'm working on a project and have simplified the problem to the code below. I want to call the function "test_2" and have the input equal y then use the input as the argument for "test_1". Is this allowed with python's rules or is there another way around this problem?

```
def test_1(X):
    if x == 1:
        print("string")

def test_2():
    y = input()
    if y == 1:
        test_1(y)
```

Comment: What happened when you ran the code?  That should give you some insight as to whether or not you can do this.  However, neither of your conditions will *ever* be `True`, because `input()` reads in a string, and you are comparing to an integer, and I'm guessing that is the real problem you are having.

Comment: @chrisz If this is Python 2, then `input` can return `1`.

Comment: @chrisz I input 1 and it returned 1. I didn't know that, is there a way to make the input read an integer?

Comment: The only real problem I see with this code is the assumption that `x` and `X` are the same variable.

Comment: @Matt7425 `y = int(input())`

Comment: It's python 3.7

Comment: @chepner Yeah, just tried test_1 on it's own and it's bringing up errors. Probably should have seen if it actually worked first before calling it.

Comment: Thanks, used int() and changed the x's to be the same and now it's working ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_1(X):
   if X == 1:
      print(X)

def test_2():
    y = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if y == 1:
        test_1(y)

test_2()
```

This code should work. If y matches the condition (==1) This will call the test_1 function within your test_2 function and should print the string. In this example I simply had it print X.

Your error is that you entered x as a capital in the function definition, but entered it as a lowercase letter in your function body based off of what you posted here. That should return a traceback. Below here is your output:

```
Enter a number: 1
1
```

Comment: Yeah, the different x's was my bad. The int() worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison in the method `test_1()` needs to be updated to check the actual parameter:

```
def test_1(x):
    if x == 1:
        print("string")

def test_2():
    y = input()
    if y == 1:
        test_1(y)

test_2()
```